# Remove the desired number from data

Tags: php

I have a question about how can I delete the desired number from the `img_ids`. As you see in the table below the `img_ids` like `68,67,66,65,64,`  . I want to delete for example number `67`, how can I do that with PHP. My mind is confused because of the commas :S.

[image]

```
<div class="delete" id="67">Delete Image</div>
```

Ajax

```
$("body").on("click", ".delete", function(){
  var deleteimgid = $(this).attr("id");
  var data = 'img='+deleteimgid;
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'delete.php',
   data: data,
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function(){},
   success: function(response){

   }
});
});
```

delete.php

```
<?php 
    include_once 'inc.php';

    if(isset($_POST['img'])){
       $imgid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $imgid);

      // Then what should be the query ? 
      // I am confused because of the commas.
    }
?>
```

Comment: Think about normalizing your database instead of storing comma separated data...really hard to handle--you will run into bigger problems related to maintainability, scalability and performance

Comment: **Don't** store multiple values in a single field. Use another table for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even tho you should not store data like that, here a working approach:

```
$imgList = '12,23,45,56,67,78';
$imgid = 12;

$imgIds = explode(',', $imgList);
$imgIds = array_filter($imgIds, function ($item) use ($imgid) {
    return $imgid != $item;
});

$imgList = implode(',', $imgIds);
print $ImgList; // prints 23,45,56,67,78
```

What it does:

1. Splitting the list of ids into an array by comma
2. Use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to map over the array and remove the desired value
3. Implode the list again by comma

---

**How you actually should/could store your data**

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should normalize your database. [Read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

You also could use a blob field instead of a text field, since PHP can handle blob data very easy using [serialize](http://php.net/serialize)/[unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize)

Comment: I really understood your answer. I will give you vote. It solved the problem. So can i ask a mini question from stackoverflow chat section ?

Comment: Sure, create a room and send me the link