# how to store data seperated with comma in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

**HTML code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>dynamic</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <form action="">  
            <div id="items">
                <input type="text" name="username">
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="add entry" id="add">
            <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
        </form> 
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").click(function (e){
event.preventDefault()
        $('#items').append('<div><input type="text" name="username">'
            +'<input type="button" value="delete" id="delete"/></div>');
    });

    $('body').on('click','#delete',function (e){
        $(this).parent('div').remove();

    });
});
```

**Database Connection**

```php
<?php
$local = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = mysql_connect($local, $username, $password);
$db= mysql_select_db( $dbname,$conn);

$n=$_POST["username"];              

$in = "INSERT INTO table(header1) VALUES ('$n') ";
if(mysql_query($in)===TRUE)
{
  echo " <h1>successfully Inserted</h1> <br>"; 


}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $in . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

DB name = test

Table name= table

I need to store values with comma Each values needs to seperate with comma,
In this above code i created dynamic textbox so there are many textbox. 
Screenshot is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Stop using **mysql_*** functions, they are deprecated

Comment: Storing data as comma separated values is not recommended. Learn how to normalize your db.

Comment: use foreach on your input field

Comment: What is the question you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an array of users in your posted data, You should first change your inputs to:

```
<input type="text" name="username[]">
```

and then in your php code, use [implode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join all users with comma separated like this:

```
$n = implode(",", $_POST["username"]);
$in = "INSERT INTO table(header1) VALUES ('$n') ";
...
```

be careful about users inputs, you should validate them before insertion, Never Trust User Input

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out already, dont store comma seperated lists in a database, normalize them instead or use a serialized blob field (not good too, but better).

Neither should you use mysql_* functions, since they have been deprecated in PHP5.6(?) and removed entirely in PHP7. Use mysqli_* or PDO instead.
Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections, because you store posted data directly into your database.

Take a look at one of my older answers, which is about the same subject (kinda): [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46732309/6622577)